# On Trello, members of my organization can't move cards to another list?

Tags: trello, permissions

I created an organization, and assigned members.
I created lists and put cards on to the lists.

However none of my members can move cards between lists. This kind of defeats the purpose. I don't see a permission for this.

What am I missing?

Furthermore, when I try to assign the card to a member, Trello doesn't seem to think that board has members because it finds no one.

Answer (score 7):

Once the new member has the board displayed, they need to click on the menu (right) and "Join Board" in order to complete the final step allowing for modification of the board.

Comment: This was the reason in our case.

Answer (score 6):

There is a difference between organization membership and board membership.

Only members of a board can perform actions on boards (like move around cards). This way, you can have boards that are only visible to or editable by a subset of your organization.

In order for members to be able to edit your boards, you'll have to add them to the boards directly.

There is also a setting to allow organization boards to be joinable by anyone in the organization. This can sometimes be more convenient than adding everyone yourself. Turn it on in the Board Settings:

[image]