# Team members on board can't add cards to the board

Tags: trello, trello-cards, permissions, trello-boards, trello-lists

I created a board and added members to it with normal permissions, and they can see the board, but they are unable to add cards to the board.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: I would contact trello if I were you. You can email them or give them a shout on twitter.

Answer (score 4):

I just had this problem. The users also have to "join" the board themselves. See here:

[On Trello, members of my organization can't move cards to another list?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/50594/on-trello-members-of-my-organization-cant-move-cards-to-another-list)